# How to open content pages through navigation menu in Xamarin native sample project

Tags: xamarin

I am new to Xamarin and building a native app.
I saw many sites explaining the left side navigation menu 
but they do not explain how to open other pages.

I wanted to show different content pages on the navigation click.

1. On one button click show only text.
2. Other button show gallery.

Please tell me how can I do this.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: which Xamarin are you using? Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: @lawiluk  Xamarin.Android (Not Forms)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start an Activity from another Activity on Xamarin Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543058/start-an-activity-from-another-activity-on-xamarin-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin.Android, when you want to navigate to a new layout, you could follow the steps below.

1. Create the layout in `Resource/Layout folder` and create `acticity.cs` in app project

   ```
   TextLayout.xml

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv_Text"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   GralleryLayout.xml

   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   ```
2. Add the control in main layout.

   ```
   <Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_TextLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Text Layout"/>
   <Button
   android:id="@+id/btn_GralleryLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@+id/btn_TextLayout"
   android:text="Grallery Layout"/>
   ```
3. Add the code below to navigate to the activity you want.

   ```
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
       // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

       var btn_TextLayout = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_TextLayout);
       btn_TextLayout.Click += Btn_TextLayout_Click;

       var btn_GralleryLayout = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_GralleryLayout);
       btn_GralleryLayout.Click += Btn_GralleryLayout_Click;
   }

   private void Btn_GralleryLayout_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(GralleryActivity));
       StartActivity(intent);
   }

   private void Btn_TextLayout_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TextActivity));
       StartActivity(intent);
   }
   ```
4. Open the view of TextLayout and GralleryLayout.

   ```
   TextActivity.cs

   SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TextLayout);
   var tv_Text = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv_Text);
   tv_Text.Text = "Only the text";

   GralleryActvity.cs

    var ImageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
       ImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.pig);
   ```

**Result:**

[image]

You could download from the `Android/App1 folder` on GitHub for reference.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

Comment: Thank you for the response and efforts. But I wanted to show a different content page, which I figured it out. Thank you so much because I needed this in next step.

Comment: @Dhruv If this reply help you, please make as answer. Thank you~

Comment: Thank you for your support. But I can not mark this as an answer because my reputation is below 15.