# Play Ringtone for One minute in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, intervals, ringtone

My alarm project is almost complete and i have code that compares current time and target time every second to see if true and play ringtone on the event that the Alarm matures. My problem is i can't seem to be able to play the ringtone for a specified period of time and then stop
Here is my Source File...

```
 class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity{
//System Timer defintion with interval of one second in class
 System.Timers.Timer _stopringtone = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

               protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  //Defining path for Ringtone's default uri
   path = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Ringtone);
  //Ringtone instance
   r = RingtoneManager.GetRingtone(Application.Context, path);
//Timer elpase event handler 
  _stopringtone.Elapsed += _stopringtone_Elapsed;
//Timer disabled by default will be enabled by alarm maturity event
 _stopringtone.Enabled = false;
   
}
//This event checks every second if the two time variables are equal and plays a ringtone alongside a vibration pattern 
 private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
           {
             //Code to check current time and target time defined here
             
               
             //Logic to compare the two variables
            if (span == span1){
            //Event Elapse method returns true so alarm time has matured, play some music and vibration
            
             //Vibration definition
                 Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
              //Vibration pattern definition
              long[] pattern = { 0, 2000, 2000 };
              //Play vibration
              vibrator.Vibrate(pattern,0);
              //Play Ringtone Uri,This is where I need code to play the ringtone for interval 60 seconds
               r.Play();
          //Alarm matured so enable timer to count down 20 seconds and shut off music
            _stopringtone.Enabled = true;

                 }
           }
//CountDown Logic method
  private void _stopringtone_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                int a = 0;
                int b = a++;
                if (b == 10)
                {
                    r.Stop();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Ringtone plays forever,i need some code to check in and manage the playback time thanks. It works now...

Comment: set a timer and stop the ringtone when it fires

Comment: Superb logic Jason , I can't believe i never thought of it, a system class timer like the one am using to trigger alarm event with?

Comment: I tried this delegate but compiler reports an error saying, ```+=``` cannot be applied to operands of type ```Timer``` and ```Anonymous method```, this is the delegate   ```_stopringtone += delegate(object sender,System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
                    {

                    };
```

Comment: you assign the delegate to the `Elapsed` event, not the `Timer`

Comment: okay am on it, custom logic is not a good approach to so engineering due to reverse engineering

Comment: Thanks Jason, i implemented the logic of the second system timer in my project as you suggested(see updated code) and it now works, only difference i had to make was to  add ```runonuithread(()=>{``` and it now works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `TimerTask` and `Timer` to schedule a specified  period of time to do something.

For example , create a **TimerTask** each second to count and stop timer task until 60 seconds.

```
class MyTask : TimerTask
{
    Timer mTimer;
    Ringtone ringtone;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public MyTask(Timer timer, Ringtone r, MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        this.mTimer = timer;
        this.ringtone = r;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
    }
    int i;
    public override void Run()
    {
        if (i < 60)
        {
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            mTimer.Cancel();
            ringtone.Stop();
            mainActivity.StartActivity(typeof(NextActivity));
        }

           
    }
}
```

Then in **Activity.cs**, we can invoke `Ringtone.Play()` in a method, such as a button clicked method:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Schedule(new MyTask(timer,r,this), 0, 1000);
    r.Play();
}
```

Comment: It worked but the timer class is a Java Utility right?

Comment: @CodeTiger Yes, you need to use `using Java.Util;` in project.https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer

Comment: Can i use it to timeout an mainactivity and launch another one?

Comment: @CodeTiger Yes, when the time over 60 seconds, you could launch another one. You could add some logics in the `else` method to determine whehter need to cancel the Timer or RingTone.

Comment: Okay thanks but the StartActivity namespace is not available in the overriding run method?

Comment: @CodeTiger You could pass the instance of `Activity` into the `MyTask` the same as `Ringtone` could be passed and used inside `Run()` method.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and put the whole thing in comment, i need that code

Comment: @CodeTiger I have updaed the answer, you could have a look.

Comment: Thanks i appreciate it,whats xxx?

Comment: @CodeTiger That's the Intent of NextActivity. You could refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26543058/start-an-activity-from-another-activity-on-xamarin-android to finish your code.

Comment: I should declare it in my class? because am getting not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @CodeTiger I have updated answer. Sorry for not too much understanding the logic of project, you could according to my sample code to use in your project to fit the logic.

Comment: Thanks, Constructor logic and internal class can really mess with programmer's head thank you, it worked

Comment: Still messing with my head, lemme try to use System Timer Lapse Event instead

Comment: @CodeTiger You could use the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netcore-3.1#examples) to check whether it works first, and you need to use click event or another separate event to start `System.Timers.Timer`. If start it in the `OnCreate` method, it will not work.

Comment: It worked already, it checks and decrements integer by one every one second, if integer ==0, it starts activity

Comment: @CodeTiger That's great!